# Worklight-related error message on application launch

Tags: jquery-mobile, push-notification, ibm-mobilefirst

I'm getting the following error message from Worklight.
The application should go live today and this error prevents it.

[image]

In initOptions.js `connecyOnStartUp : false` but I'm calling `WL.Client.connect` manually.
I have a doubt that it's related to the push notifications registration. Actually I'm registering anonymous users to an anonymous push event source using PERSISTENT_COOKIE as user id.
This is happening on my client's devices but not on mines.

---

This is my security realm definitions:

```
    <customSecurityTest name="LmsrSecurityTest">
            <test isInternalUserID="true" realm="LmsrAuthRealm" step="1"/>
            <test realm="wl_deviceNoProvisioningRealm" isInternalDeviceID="true" step="2"/>
            <test realm="wl_antiXSRFRealm"/>
<!--            <test realm="wl_authenticityRealm"/> -->
            <test realm="wl_remoteDisableRealm"/>
        </customSecurityTest>  
        <!-- Anoymous users notifications -->       
        <mobileSecurityTest name="notLoggedInTest">
            <testAppAuthenticity/> 
            <testDeviceId provisioningType="none" />
            <testUser realm="wl_anonymousUserRealm" />
```

UPDATE : Here is my application descriptor

```
<iphone bundleId="<my-bundle-id>" version="1.0.1">
        <worklightSettings include="false"/>
        <pushSender password="XXXXX"/>
        <security>
            <encryptWebResources enabled="false"/>
            <testWebResourcesChecksum enabled="false" ignoreFileExtensions="png, jpg, jpeg, gif, mp4, mp3"/>
        </security>
    </iphone>
    <android version="1.0.1">
        <worklightSettings include="false"/>
        <pushSender key="XXXXXX" senderId="XXXXX"/>
        <security>
            <encryptWebResources enabled="false"/>
            <testWebResourcesChecksum enabled="false" ignoreFileExtensions="png, jpg, jpeg, gif, mp4, mp3"/>
            <publicSigningKey>my-very-long-public-signing-key</publicSigningKey>
        </security>
    </android>
```

Here is the logs server side when it happens:

> [9/27/14 18:42:46:893 GST] 0000057b
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.util.ApplicationErrorUtils           E
>   SRVE0777E: Exception thrown by application class
>   'com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationContext.pushCurrentResource:398'
>   com.worklight.server.auth.api.WorkLightAuthenticationException    at
>   com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationContext.pushCurrentResource(AuthenticationContext.java:398)
>     at
>   com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationServiceBean.accessResource(AuthenticationServiceBean.java:75)
>     at
>   com.worklight.integration.services.impl.DataAccessServiceImpl.subscribeNotifications(DataAccessServiceImpl.java:166)
>     at
>   com.worklight.gadgets.serving.handler.NotificationSubscriptionHandler.doPost(NotificationSubscriptionHandler.java:100)
>     at
>   com.worklight.gadgets.serving.GadgetAPIServlet.doGetOrPost(GadgetAPIServlet.java:141)
>     at
>   com.worklight.gadgets.serving.GadgetAPIServlet.doPost(GadgetAPIServlet.java:103)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:595)     at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:668)  at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1240)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:760)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:443)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:127)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:88)
>     at
>   com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationFilter$1.execute(AuthenticationFilter.java:191)
>     at
>   com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationServiceBean.accessResource(AuthenticationServiceBean.java:76)
>     at
>   com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationFilter.java:195)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:194)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:85)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:949)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1029)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.CacheServletWrapper.handleRequest(CacheServletWrapper.java:78)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:885)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.DynamicVirtualHost$2.run(DynamicVirtualHost.java:252)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.http.dispatcher.internal.channel.HttpDispatcherLink$TaskWrapper.run(HttpDispatcherLink.java:584)
>     at com.ibm.ws.threading.internal.Worker.executeWork(Worker.java:439)
>     at com.ibm.ws.threading.internal.Worker.run(Worker.java:421)    at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
>
> [9/27/14 18:42:47:137 GST] 0000057b
>   com.worklight.core.auth.ext.AuthenticityLoginModule          E
>   FWLSE0127E: Authenticity check failed. [project Fahr]

Comment: This has got nothing to do with push notifications... Was the application already installed on the device and the customer upgraded to iOS8? You need to make sure to use the latest iFix for all worklight releases.

Comment: This error is more related to App Authenticity and/or web resources checksum test.

Comment: I'm already using the version 6.1.0.2 dated from september 2014.

Comment: Is there something that I can do to debug/fix it ?

Comment: It happens on android as well !

Comment: It would help if you'll actually explain what you are experiencing on the devices. Provides logs, etc.

Comment: Does it still happen if you remove and reinstall the app from the customer device? does it happen in yours after you remove it from your device? provide reproduction, something to work with...

Comment: Actually it does not happen on my devices that's why I can't catch any logs. On all customer's devices they are having the same. Some are testing on ios 7.1.2 and some other are testing on Android. I'm updating the question with secrity config snippets

Comment: That is not going to help. You need to get logs from the customer or recreate it in your devices.

Comment: Here is some logs that I got from a device: http://pastebin.com/EQ069qVy

Comment: Unfortunately the logs are not very revealing; I suggest that you will open a PMR so that IBM support could help you.

Comment: Idan, please check the logs server side when it happens. I just captured it

Answer (score 1):

Judging by the server log, this error is not related to push notifications.
The server log mention a failure with the Application Authenticity challenge:

```
[9/27/14 18:42:47:137 GST] 0000057b com.worklight.core.auth.ext.AuthenticityLoginModule E FWLSE0127E: Authenticity check failed. [project Fahr]
```

- To verify, you can *disable* the authenticity check from Worklight Console for either the iPhone or Android environment.
- If the application then successfully connects to the Worklight Server, you need to to double-check how you have set it up.
- Read the [Application Authenticity Protection training module](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v620/09_15_Application_Authenticity_Protection.pdf) as well as [the user documentation topic](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/search/authenticity?scope=SSNJXP) (pick the correct topic for your Worklight version).

Possible reasons could be wrong `bundleId`/`applicationId`/public signing key (depending on the Worklight version and affected environment).

Note that any configuration change will require redeployment of the .war file to the application server, as well as a redeployment of the .wlapp to the server and of the application to the device/App Store.

Comment: In fact Authenticity select box is disabled in the worklight console. Because I don't want it to be there. I disabled it from application descriptor. Please advise if something is wrong with my configuration. the app connects successfully for the fist time using WL.Client.connect

Comment: Did you read my answer? The logs says that there is an authenticity error. So double-check your setup, make sure it is disabled and RE-DEPLOY THE WAR AND WLAPP AND APPLICATION. That is my only advice. I cannot help further.

Comment: ok thanks Idan, I just wanted to check that from configuration point I miss nothing

Comment: Your configuration looks OK, but something is missing if it is failing on authenticity even if you say you disabled it, which is why I recommended to double-check the setup and deploy the required resources.

Comment: If I'm doing an ADHoc deplyment for iOS does it have any impact ? because I read that the bundle id for ios should be the same

Comment: That doesn't matter for App Authenticity. Per the instructions, what matters is that the bundleId in application-descriptor.xml will match the bundleId used in Xcode.

Comment: BTW, you wrote you don't want app authenticity, so just remove the security test in the authenticationConfig.xml and re-deploy the .war and .wlapp and re-install the app in the device to make sure everything is properly synced.